# Multi authentication in laravel5.5 with role specific users

Tags: laravel-5.5

How to implement multiple authentication with one model named `User`? There are different roles attached to this model. I need to implement multiple authentication as user and administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Better not to call it “multi authentication”. Multi authentication is a completely different conecpt. Basically you will have to have 2 guards setup. 
But if you are using one single guard (user guard in this case) you will have to simply assign roles by creating a new column in users model called “roles” or what ever you prefer.
After you have setup the roles colum in your users model, create a middleware and configure the rest. Explanation:

In your “role” middleware or whatever you prefer, specify what roles are which and who has access to where. And include that middleware inside your controller in use.

If you stil want to have a multi authentication like one login and redirect separately for users and administrators, I’d suggest you to look at “the dev marketer” multi auth tutorial. It is a well explained and all the source code can be found in whole on github.

Keep in mind that the laravels default /login route is meant for normal user login (atleast for me). You can create a /admin/login route with the above mentioned tutorial.

Hope this helps. Good luck :)